# How to make links work in Twitter Tweets? API + json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

Can anybody make my twitter links work?
I tried to find the answer on the Twitter API page, but can't find it..

See here [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Autodealers/XSmYa/).

Thank you in advanced!
With Kind Regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function to your code to parse URLs:

```
function parseLinks(tweet) {
    return tweet.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/g, function (tweet) {
        return tweet.link(tweet);
    });
};
```

And then parse the text of the tweet through this function before displaying it:

```
timeline.append(
    $('<li>').append(
        $('<strong>').text(created_at),
        $('<span>').html('<br />' + parseLinks(_this.text))
    )
);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XSmYa/10/)

Comment: Hi again, do you also know the script how to open those links in a new window? That would finish it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = _this.text.split(/\s+/);
for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i];
    if (word.substr(0, 7) == 'http://' || word.substr(0, 8) == 'https://') {
        words[i] = '<a href="'+word+'">'+word+'</a> ';
    }
}
var text = words.join(' ');
```